# tmux: refresh the list of windows when the session name is renamed from within the script

Tags: tmux

In tmux i use `ctrl + b`,`s` to see the list of windows in collapsed mode

Inside my script which is running in a session will rename the session name in between. I want the renamed session name to be reflected in the list while i am browsing

I am using the below code to rename the session name from my script in whichever session this script is running:

```
session_name=`tmux display-message -p "#S"`
tmux rename-session -t ${session_name} DOWN_COMP_${session_name}
```

Or Is there a shortcut to refresh the list if its not possible to reflect the changes immediately

Answer (score 0):

If you expand and then collapse a session it will rebuild the list and should show the new name.